# testcase not running in c program

Tags: c, debugging, testcase

iam new to c program and facing difficulty in debugging programs.In the below code test case 2 is not running.I have found that the error is in reading interger n in the second test case.someone please hep me with this issue.Also please recommend me with some tools that can be ued for debugging c programs using terminal.Thanks for help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read(){
   int r = 0;
   char c = getchar_unlocked();
   while(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
      r = r*10 + c - 48 ;
      c = getchar_unlocked();
   }
   return r;
}

void main(){
   int t = 0;
   t = read();
   int rr = 0;
   for(rr = 0;rr < t;rr++){
      int i,n = 0;
      n = read();
      int *p = (int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
      for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
         *(p+i) = getchar_unlocked() - 48;
      }
      int no,nz = 0;
      for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
         if(*(p+i) == 0){nz += 1;}
         if(*(p+i) == 1){no += 1;}
      }
      int k = 0;
      if(((no)%2 == 0) && ((nz)%2) == 0){
         k = -1;
      }
      if(((no)%2 == 0) && ((nz)%2) == 1){
         k = 0;
      }
      if(((no)%2 == 1) && ((nz)%2) == 0){
         k = 1;
      }
      if(((no)%2 == 1) && ((nz)%2) == 1){
         k = 1;
      }
      int result = 0;printf("%d\n",5556);
      if(k == 1){
         for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
            if(*(p+i) == 1){
               result = i+1 ;
               break;
            }
         }

      }
      if(k == 0){
         for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
            if(*(p+i) == 0){
               result = i+1 ;
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      printf("%d\n",result);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is test case 2? What platform are you using?

Comment: iam using gcc linux and i implemented test cases using for loop.here testcase 2 means 2nd iteration of for loop.

Comment: What's your input and expected output? You can use `gdb` to debug in linux.

Comment: I wrote this code to solve one of the problems in codechef.The test cases are same as shown in that problem.http://www.codechef.com/SNCK151B/problems/MXZERO

Comment: 1) 'read()' is a known system function call (the prototype is part of the stdio.h header file.)  strongly suggest changing that name.  2) the return type from the main() function is ALWAYS 'int', not 'void'  (should also have a statement at the end of main() 'return(0);'
)    3) with gcc, use parameters: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' so the warnings are displayed, so you can fix them.

Comment: the man pages says about 'getchar_unlocked()'   the *_unlocked()' functions are thread UNsafe.   "The nonstandard *_unlocked() variants occur on a few UNIX systems,  and are available in recent glibc.  They should probably not be used.
"

Comment: I see several 'for' loops, please clarify.  Please include an example of: inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs,

Comment: the system function: getchar_unlocked(), returns an int, not a char.   This enables checking for EOF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy to read an integer is flawed. You don't have the logic to skip whitespaces. I would change the function name to `read_int` and change its implementation to

```
int read(){
   int n;
   if ( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
   {
       // Deal with the error
   }
   return n;
}
```

Also, change

```
*(p+i) = getchar_unlocked() - 48;
```

to

```
*(p+i) = read_int();
```

or a more intuitive version:

```
p[i] = read_int();
```

With those changes, I am able to read and process the numbers. But I still get the wrong output. I'll let you figure the logic error in your code.

**Additional Comments**

`main` is expected to return an `int`. If your compiler didn't complain about that, it's time to up the warning level. I use `-Wall` by default.

When you are in the process of debugging your code, it's always good to test the code that reads the input to make sure that there is no error in reading the input.

Here's what I did to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_int(){
   int n;
   if ( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
   {
      // Deal with the error.
   }
   return n;
}

int main(){
   int t = 0;
   int rr = 0;

   t = read_int();
   printf("t = %d\n", t);

   for(rr = 0;rr < t;rr++){
      int i,n = 0;

      n = read_int();
      printf("n = %d\n", n);

      int *p = (int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
      for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
         p[i] = read_int();
         printf("p[%d] = %d\n", i, p[i]);
      }

      int no,nz = 0;
      for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
         if(*(p+i) == 0){nz += 1;}
         if(*(p+i) == 1){no += 1;}
      }

      int k = 0;
      if(((no)%2 == 0) && ((nz)%2) == 0){
         k = -1;
      }
      if(((no)%2 == 0) && ((nz)%2) == 1){
         k = 0;
      }
      if(((no)%2 == 1) && ((nz)%2) == 0){
         k = 1;
      }
      if(((no)%2 == 1) && ((nz)%2) == 1){
         k = 1;
      }

      int result = 0;
      // printf("%d\n",5556);
      if(k == 1){
         for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
            if(*(p+i) == 1){
               result = i+1 ;
               break;
            }
         }

      }

      if(k == 0){
         for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
            if(*(p+i) == 0){
               result = i+1 ;
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      printf("%d\n",result);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from calloc() and family of functions.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from calloc() and family of functions to assure the operation was successful